# When to create a custom module?

Tags: php, oop, kohana, kohana-3

I'm trying to fully understand the circumstances when I'd create a module, over say creating various models and helpers (which may or may not extend other classes)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would create a module for anything that is not related to a specific application. The idea is that you create reusable modules which can be used in multiple projects.

Some people even split there entire application up into multiple modules.

A good example of this is zombor's [vendo](http://github.com/vendo/vendo) application, which basically is an example application where you can learn alot from.

Comment: Right! So he doesn't even have an application/classes folder? So by creating modules for everything, and abstracting these modules you make your code more reusable. Am I right in thinking then that if I had two modules 'User' (which creates a basic user object) and 'Groups' (which is essentialy only an abstract class that groups multiple objects together) I would then create a new class in the 'User' module /modules/user/classes/user/list.php which extends the groups module and creates lists of users?

Comment: Is it best practice though? I guess what I'm getting at is if I have two modules A and B, and I want a to make use of B, is it best to create a new module or simply add a class within A to do that. This of course would mean A would then depend on B and therfore isn't abstracted to its fullest extent? So would not having three modules be best 'User', 'Groups' and 'Usergroup'?

Comment: There is no simple answer to that question. It totaly depends on the situation. But you don't have to make a module for each class. Try to group similar things together. One distinction you can make is the amount of coupling. If things are highly related, you can decide to put them in the same module. When they're not so related, you could put them in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

@Ikke point is valid. Another way is that a module has a specific purpouse, like containing classes, global functions, global types for a shared goal, wheter can be used in a single application or several.

Modules for several applications are usually called "librar-y (ies)"

Comment: But in kohana there is just a modules folder for grouping classes and plugging them in. Aren't libraries in kohana a single class in the `/application/classes/` folder that aren't static?

Comment: @Colin, I don't work with kohana, but, speaking very conceptually, if you put a class into a module, without any static stuff, and there is a reason to put it there, separate from others, its a library ;-)